# Visual Studio 2010:one or more solutions were not loaded correctly Windows 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I copied my project from my memory stick into my work machine. Every time I try to open my project I have this message box saying:

```
one or more solutions were not loaded correctly,Please see the output Window for detail
```

When I close this message box, I have only the name of my project with (unavailable)! Also When I try to close the Visual studio, a file called Name.Sou opens automatically!! I thought It was the main reason, so I deleted this file and tried to reopen again, but it keeps showing me the same message!

I have this project works perfectly on my USB stick, but it this error generates every time I try to copy the project into a file !

I know this question was already asked, but there was no clear solution for this problem! Can anyone help me please or guides me of what to do to solve this issue.

Comment: `Please see the output Window for details` What does the output window say?

Comment: That file is just the user options file, it is likely unrelated. Please post the error message.

Comment: Nothing in the output window and its only shows one or more solutions were not loaded correctly,Please see the output Window for detail as a message box pop up

Comment: Click on the project name and look at the properties. Most likely, it's trying to load the project from the wrong location. At worst, remove the project from the solution and re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the necessary SDK's.

For me the issue `The project type is not supported by this installation.` was related to a missing framework installation.